# Install Comodo PositiveSSL in to Debian 8

Tags: ssl, nginx

before a few days ago, i bought a SSL certificate - Comodo PositiveSSL. 
From my hosting provider, give me a these three files:

- mail.domain.com.key.txt
- mail_domain_com.crt
- mail_domain_com.ca-bundle

I installed self signed certs many times, on my nginx server :), but these is ... confused for me. I read many themes (like [this](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/)) , everything is look fine, but i can't understand why private key is never suggested how to use. I understand how can combined .crt * .ca-bundle into one file .crt, if that is true. When use private key, who give me from hosting company, nginx return error:

`nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mail.domain.com.key.txt") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)`

I tried this on my VPS server, with debian 8 OS, if matters.
If you have other questions, please tell me and i edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, somebody open .key file with windows editor and every new line was break. When i convert with 
`dos2unix`
everything look fine :)